# KineticJS - Drawing a simple line - Kinetic.Line - Strange Behavior - Possibly a bug?

Tags: drawing, line, kineticjs

I have the following code in a simple, html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js">            </script>
<script>

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150],
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineJoin: 'round'
  });

  layer.add(redLine);
  stage.add(layer);
</script>
```

This code is supposed to draw a very simple, single line, from the top, left of the browser space, to 150, 150.

However, when I test this, nothing is drawn on the page.

I'm on Windows Vista Business, up to date, I'm using Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m.

Now, if I add another set of points in the points array - to look like this:

```
points: [0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150, 300, 300],
```

when I reload the page including this change, the code works as expected.

Now, further play and research, turned that, if I want to keep this array:

```
points: [0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150],
```

I have to add the following, in the line configuration code:

```
dashArray: [1, 1]
```

with the "dashArray" property, the line is correctly drawn with the initial array problem.

```
  var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150],
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineCap: 'round',
    lineJoin: 'round',
    dashArray: [1, 1]
  });
```

Is this a bug?

Is this expected behavior? I cannot find any documentation about this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ff4sD/

Additional info: I can reproduce this behavior in several kineticjs versions:

v3.10.5 and 4.3.0-beta2 as demonstrated in this example.

Answer (score 1):

If certain elements are not being drawn on the screen you should call:

```
 .draw()
```

on either the stage or the layer containing the item. For example:

```
 stage.draw(); or layer.draw();
```

This redraws the stage or layer.

More info:

The way that javascript execution works is not always the way we think, basically, your code is not executing at the time you think it should be. You need something to trigger the drawing after the stage is created. Simply put, you could add a window.onload function or document.onready function to draw the stage when the page loads. A different solution would be to have the draw triggered by a different event, such as click. So you could create a button, with an onclick attribute and have it trigger stage drawing.

Like so:

html:

```
     <button onclick='javascript:myRedraw()'>Redraw</button>
```

javascript:

```
    function myRedraw(){
        stage.draw();
    }
```

Here is an update: http://jsfiddle.net/ff4sD/2/

Comment: To note, your jsfiddle worked fine for me in all browsers. Did you experience the same thing? And is it not working in all your browsers?

Comment: Really?? Strange. It might be a mix of the Browser / OS perhaps?
For me it works on every browser except Chrome - I'm on Windows Vista Business, up to date, I'm using Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97 m.

Comment: I tried the code with stage.draw() and it still does not work. I strongly feel this is a bug. Thanks for following this up.

Comment: Then it seems that the bug is with chrome on Vista. I've tested it on a Mac in a few browsers and on Windows 7 in the same browsers and it all works fine. What if you and more objects to the layer. Like add another line?